# Do loops by group in R

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

Newbie question. I have a dataset that I am using to calculate some accounting values. The dataset looks like this

```
    ID   Period   Amount Interest O_Bal   C_Bal
    1     1        1234    0.07     1234  (1234+(1234*0.07)) = 1321
    1     2        1244    0.07     1321  (1321-1234+(1321*0.07))
    1     3           .....
    2     1            ......

...
```

Please ignore the actual values in the table. What I have at the moment is the first row for each ID. I need to create a loop for each ID group so that from period 2 onwards, it calculates the closing balance as per the formula in the second row. Any ideas?

I have tried the following

```
   fin_calc$C_Bal = fin_calc$O_Bal + (fin_calc$O_Bal*0.07)

if (fin_calc$Period==1) {
  fin_calc$Cl_Bal = fin_calc$C_Bal
}

fin_c <- fin_calc %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Cl_Bal = lag(Cl_Bal) - Amount_PA + (lag(Cl_Bal) - Amount_PA)*0.07)
```

What this is doing is its able to continue from period 1 to period 2 but then subsequent periods are calculated incorrectly

```
 Data <- data.frame(
    ID = 1,
    Period = c(1,2,3),
    Amount_PA = c(0,2946737,3035139),
    O_Bal = c(30979981.5,0,0),
    C_Bal = c(33148580.2,0,0),
    Cl_Bal = c(33148580.2,32221382.2,-3345026.6)

  )
```

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data we can work with, all necessary code, and a clear explanation of what you're trying to do and what hasn't worked.

Comment: Apologies. Question updated.

Comment: This still isn't data we can work with

Comment: Ok. Updated. Hopefully this is the suitable format for data.

Answer (score 0):

If, like you say, you have the first row of all ID's and all ID's follow that exact same pattern, maybe you could try:

```
library(dplyr)
df%>%
group_By(ID)%>%
mutate(Closing_Bal = ifelse(is.na(lag(Opening_Bal),
Opening_Bal + (Opening_bal*Interest),
Opening_Bal - lag(Opening_Bal) + (Opening_bal*Interest))))
```

**EDIT:**

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
  mutate(Cl_Bal = lag(Cl_Bal) - Amount + (lag(Cl_Bal) - Amount)*0.07) %>% 
  mutate(Cl_Bal = ifelse(Cl_Bal < 0,lag(Cl_Bal) - Amount + (lag(Cl_Bal) - Amount)*0.07,Cl_Bal))
```

Comment: Thanks for this Aaron. I am still struggling to make it work. Have updated my original question to show the issue.

Comment: @user2641784 I think the problem comes from the fact that the column you're basing your calculations on doesn't exist at the moment of calculation (The value it's picking is 0) which gives the wrong result

Comment: Thanks @Aaron. But that still did not do the trick. I have 2 periods being calculated correctly but then the subsequent periods are coming as negative